# Pandas melt multiple columns to tabulate a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
               'M_start_date_1':[201709,201709, 201709],
               'M_end_date_1':[201905, 201905, 201905],
               'M_start_date_2':[202004, 202004, 202004],
               'M_end_date_2':[202005, 202005, 202005],
               'F_start_date_1':[201803, 201803, 201803],
               'F_end_date_1':[201904, 201904, 201904],
               'F_start_date_2':[201912, 201912, 201912],
               'F_end_date_2':[202007, 202007, 202007],                   
               })
```

I need to tabulate it and create a new column based on prefix in columns [1:],
to get this output:
[image]

I was trying to use pandas.melt function but got stuck with multiple variables.
Did someone worked with this function for multiple columns or there is another way to obtain the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main idea is convert `id` column to `index`, then `split` all another columns by `_` for `MultiIndex` and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then for correct order is used [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), remove unnecessary levels by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), set index names for new columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last convert it to columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = (df1.stack(level=[0,2,3])
          .sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False])
          .reset_index(level=[2,3], drop=True)
          .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
          .rename_axis(['id','cod'])
          .reset_index())
print (df1)
    id cod   start     end
0    1   M  201709  201905
1    1   M  202004  202005
2    1   F  201803  201904
3    1   F  201912  202007
4    2   M  201709  201905
5    2   M  202004  202005
6    2   F  201803  201904
7    2   F  201912  202007
8    3   M  201709  201905
9    3   M  202004  202005
10   3   F  201803  201904
11   3   F  201912  202007
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you @jezrael very much!! I always like your solutions. So clear and with understandable explanation . I even have a manual for all your pandas solutions that i use a lot :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Start with `Transpose` and `str.split()` labels:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id').T.reset_index()
df1.columns=['s','d0','d1','d2']
df2 = df1.join (df1['s'].str.split('_', expand=True))
df2.columns=['s','d0','d1','d2','cod','d','date','id']
df2 = df2[['id', 'cod', 'd', 'd0','d1','d2']]

  id cod      d      d0      d1      d2
0  1   M  start  201709  201709  201709
1  1   M    end  201905  201905  201905
2  2   M  start  202004  202004  202004
3  2   M    end  202005  202005  202005
4  1   F  start  201803  201803  201803
5  1   F    end  201904  201904  201904
6  2   F  start  201912  201912  201912
7  2   F    end  202007  202007  202007
```

Then you can melt it like this:

```
df2.melt(id_vars = ['id', 'cod', 'd'], 
    value_vars = ['d0','d1','d2'], 
    value_name='date', var_name='row_id',)

   id cod      d row_id    date
0   1   M  start     d0  201709
1   1   M    end     d0  201905
2   2   M  start     d0  202004
3   2   M    end     d0  202005
......
```

How to make the rest of the transformation depends on your data. What is confusing in your example is that you have same numbers in all 3 rows and you use `id` both for rows and in column headers. Please update the question if more help still needed.

one option is `pivot_table()`:

```
df3.pivot_table(index=['id','cod','row_id'], columns = ['d'],  values='date')

d                 end   start
id cod row_id                
1  F   d0      201904  201803
       d1      201904  201803
       d2      201904  201803
   M   d0      201905  201709
       d1      201905  201709
       d2      201905  201709
2  F   d0      202007  201912
       d1      202007  201912
       d2      202007  201912
   M   d0      202005  202004
       d1      202005  202004
       d2      202005  202004
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Ruslan S. It may come in handy for next step in my exercise. The reason why data for all id's is the same, is just because it's an example. In real data i have different numbers.  Thank you!

Comment: glad to help. See example expanded with pivot_table. The solution from @jezrael is quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'id', 
    names_to = ('cod', '.value', 'num'), 
    names_pattern = r"(.)_(.+)_date_(\d)", 
    sort_by_appearance = True)
.drop(columns='num')
)

    id cod   start     end
0    1   M  201709  201905
1    1   M  202004  202005
2    1   F  201803  201904
3    1   F  201912  202007
4    2   M  201709  201905
5    2   M  202004  202005
6    2   F  201803  201904
7    2   F  201912  202007
8    3   M  201709  201905
9    3   M  202004  202005
10   3   F  201803  201904
11   3   F  201912  202007
```